# ZF2 Unit test album module returns routing issue

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework2

I am trying out the phpunit in the Zf2 album module. I encountered an error which states about routing.

Below is the debug information. It says 'Route with name "album" not found', but when I checked module.config.php in the album module folder, I see that is correctly set and in the browser the redirection to that route is working fine.

```
Album\Controller\AlbumControllerTest::testDeleteActionCanBeAccessed
Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException: Route with name "album" not found
D:\www\zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack.php:292
D:\www\zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Url.php:88
D:\www\zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Redirect.php:54
D:\www\zend2\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:80
D:\www\zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php:87
D:\www\zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:468
D:\www\zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:208
D:\www\zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php:108
D:\www\zend2\tests\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumControllerTest.php:35
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit:46
```

I understand that the issue in AlbumController.php line 80 is

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
```

But not sure why it is not working. Any one has encountered and overcome such issues?

Comment: Encountered yes, I have not overcome this yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will save approx. 30 minutes of searching in the zend framework 2 code:

```
class AlbumControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

//...

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $bootstrap        = \Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');
        $this->controller = new AlbumController();
        $this->request    = new Request();
        $this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
        $this->event      = $bootstrap->getMvcEvent();

        $router = new \Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack();
        $options = array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
            );
        $route = \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment::factory($options);

        $router->addRoute('album', $route);

        $this->event->setRouter($router);
        $this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
        $this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
        $this->controller->setEventManager($bootstrap->getEventManager());
        $this->controller->setServiceLocator($bootstrap->getServiceManager());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid duplicate Code, you can load your Routes from Module Config:

```
$module = new \YourNameSpace\Module();
$config = $module->getConfig();

$route = \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment::factory($config['router']['routes']['Home']['options']);

$router = new \Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack();
$router->addRoute('Home', $route);
```

Comment: I think this code still miss the code `$this->event->setRouter($router);` after `addRoute` to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easy way is to get the config data from the service manager:

```
$config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
```

Full code for the function `setUp()`:

```
protected function setUp() {
    $serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
    $this -> controller = new AlbumController();
    $this -> request = new Request();
    $this -> routeMatch = new RouteMatch(
        array(
            'controller' => 'index',
        )
    );
    $this -> event = new MvcEvent();
    $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
    $routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router']  : array();
    $router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);
    $this -> event -> setRouter($router);
    $this -> event -> setRouteMatch($this -> routeMatch);
    $this -> controller -> setEvent($this -> event);
    $this -> controller -> setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
}
```